# WPF: Data Binding with an ObservableCollection passed as parameter in a UserControl constructor

Tags: wpf, binding, constructor, user-controls

I have a UserControl with a ComboBox in it and I'm binding an ObservableCollection to it such as follow. Right now the collection is populated in the UserControl. However, I would like to create the ObservableCollection in the MainWindow and have another constructor for my UserControl. here's what I got now and it's working:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxInfo> Items { get; private set; }

public CustomComboBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxInfo>();
    cmb.ItemsSource = Items;

    if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        this.createNameComboBox(); // ObservatoryCollection populating       
    }           
}
```

I tried implementing a second constructor and moving the collection populating function in the Main Window but I get an error saying my comboBox in the UserControl is not set to an instance of an object. Ideally I would like something like this:

```cs
public CustomComboBox(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxInfo> Items)
{
    this.Items = Items
    // Not sure if the binding should be done here or in default constructor
}
```

Any idea how to properly do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should include a [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) which would be set as a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your User Control.

This ViewModel should contain and expose the ObservableCollection as a public property, ideally it should use some injected service provider to obtain the data from some data store and populate the ObservableCollection with that data, Finally, the ComboBox from your User Control should bind to that ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.

Your User Control code-behind should have no code other than some event handlers to manipulate the UI in response to UI events if necessary...

That is how things are done properly in WPF utilizing the MVVM pattern.

Here is an [example](http://wpftutorial.net/ReferenceArchitecture.html) of how a service is injected into the VM constructor and used to populate a collection with some data:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
        Customers = new ListCollectionView(customerService.Customers);
    }

    public ICollectionView Customers { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the MVVM pattern but I'll read more on it to fully understand it.